# WPF: How to scroll Grid with a ScrollBar?

Tags: wpf, grid, scrollbar

I know you can wrap a Grid in a ScrollViewer, and the scrolling works automatically. However, I want to make my own scrollbars around the grid. So far, I managed to sync the scrollbar with the grid when I move around the grid. However, I couldn't find properties or methods of the Grid to make it scroll when I click the scrollbar. I'm sure it's doable because SchollViewer is already doing it. Your tip is much appreciated.

UPDATE:
In fact, what I want is to create a Excel-spreadsheet like control. I created the spreadsheet using Grid layout and it seems working fine. However, I run into a problem in scrolling. Adding a ScrollViewer around the Grid will make the whole Grid scroll. However, I want to be able to freeze some rows and/or columns from scrolling. Also, using ScrollViewer, the horizontal scrollbar covers the whole bottom. But, like in Excel, I'd like to leave some space for adding some tabs. Is this possible just through restyling of the ScrollViewer?

I find a post at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e495a0cb-0104-4475-8627-3b40cd617fc1 which suggests to split grid in several sub-grids to achieve freezing headers. However, it doesn't work well if you have many columns. Furthermore, this approach is not flexible enough to allow user to choose freezing area.

Comment: Is there a reason you are building a custom scrollviewer?

Comment: Well, I want to make a customized scrollbar more like Excel scrollbar.

Comment: Its WPF, just style your scrollbar however you want it to look.

Answer (score 0):

Styling scrollbars can be a bit tricky, but I have a style to get you started (based of Expression style), you can just remove the bits you dont need/want and change colors etc.

Scollbar style example:

```
<Color x:Key="MainColor">#FF595959</Color>
<Color x:Key="BlackColor">#FF000000</Color>
<Color x:Key="WhiteColor">#FFFFFFFF</Color>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="{StaticResource MainColor}" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" Color="#FF393939" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#FFD1D1D1" />

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" EndPoint="0.5,0.971" StartPoint="0.5,0.042">
    <GradientStop Color="#4C000000" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#26FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
    <GradientStop Color="#4C000000" Offset="0.467" />
    <GradientStop Color="#26FFFFFF" Offset="0.479" />
</LinearGradientBrush>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.8"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0.3"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOn">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOff">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0.3"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="1" />
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}" Opacity="0.3" Height="Auto" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true" />
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" x:Name="HoverOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOff}" x:Name="PressedOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOn}" x:Name="PressedOn_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="ContentPresenter" Value="0.1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NuclearThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.8"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0.3"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOn">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="0.1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="PressedOff">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0.3"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="Grid">
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="HoverRectangle" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="4" Stroke="{x:Null}" Margin="4.5,-2,4.5,-2" Opacity="0.3" MinHeight="10">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource WhiteColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PressedRectangle" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="4" Stroke="{x:Null}" Margin="4.5,-2,4.5,-2" Opacity="0.3" MinHeight="10">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource WhiteColor}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" />
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" x:Name="HoverOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" >
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Grid" Value="0.1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOff}" x:Name="PressedOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressedOn}" x:Name="PressedOn_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NuclearScrollRepeatButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Background="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RepeatButton x:Name="DecreaseRepeat" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Path Margin="4.742,3.997,4.946,5.327" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Fill="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M5.2422477,11.132184 L11.5544,11.132184 8.6412958,4.4969033 z" x:Name="DecreaseArrow" />
                        </Grid>
                    </RepeatButton>
                    <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track" Orientation="Vertical" IsDirectionReversed="true">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb Style="{DynamicResource NuclearThumbStyle}" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>
                    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" x:Name="IncreaseRepeat" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path Margin="4.742,3.997,4.946,5.327" x:Name="IncreaseArrow" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Fill="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{DynamicResource GlyphBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M5.2422477,11.132184 L11.5544,11.132184 8.6412958,4.4969033 z" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                        <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0" />
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                    </RepeatButton>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="GridRoot">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" TargetName="DecreaseRepeat" />
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" TargetName="IncreaseRepeat" />
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" TargetName="PageDown" />
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" TargetName="PageUp" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Style:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your style. In fact, I'm not concerned about the appearance of the scrollbars. It actually come down to two problems: 1. How to freeze part of Grid (e.g. grid header, but could be more than header) from scrolling. 2. How to add extra stuff next to the horizontal scrollbar like tabs in Excel. Looking at ScrollViewer around a Grid, I couldn't figure out how to do those two things.